# nginx permission denied error on get

Tags: linux, nginx, redhat

For some reason i'm getting permission denied error while reading the file using nginx and in rhel6, here is my output of the log file

```
  tail -f /var/log/nginx/ph-repo.error.log
```

and the logs says

```
 "/opt/nginx/nginx-1.8.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.20.5.236, server: my-repo, request: "GET /nginx/nginx-1.8.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm HTTP/1.1", host: "my-repo"
```

When i check the permission of the file it's 777

```
[root@my-repo]# ls -l nginx/nginx-1.8.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 360628 Oct 23 02:59 nginx/nginx-1.8.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
```

The nginx process is also running as root

```
[root@ph-repo]# ps -elf | grep nginx
1 S root      1527     1  0  80   0 - 11195 rt_sig 09:48 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
5 S root      1528  1527  0  80   0 - 11378 ep_pol 09:48 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
0 S root      3062  2258  0  80   0 - 25827 pipe_w 10:52 pts/1    00:00:00 grep nginx
```

The ACL

```
[root@my-repo]# getfacl nginx
# file: nginx
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx

[root@my-repo]# getfacl nginx/nginx-1.8.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
# file: nginx/nginx-1.8.0-1.el6.ngx.x86_64.rpm
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

I'm not sure what's wrong is happening here can some one help me on this please

Comment: The error message indicates that there is a GET request to my-repo which is failing.  It's nothing to do with file permissions.

Comment: The GET is working for other directory only for this directory it;s not working so i'm confused why this is happening

Comment: Have you checked permissions on all parent directories?

Comment: yes all the parent directory i have made now 777

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is mostly the owner of the file,

```
su
cd /var/www
sudo chown www-data:www-data -R *
```

this is put the file under the same user as that of nginx/apache, should resolve your issue